# Can cnosdb support delayed deletion

Tags: cnosdb

In my work with cnosdb, I have found that when a resource is deleted (tenant, database, table), it is immediately deleted and cannot be restored. If accidentally deleted can lead to irretrievable. I would like to ask if cnosdb can delay deletion and provide a recovery mechanism